# fix System.NullReferenceException in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i m developing a website and stuck with  System.NullReferenceException .
on the master page I m using this code

```
if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("content.aspx"))
{
    if (Request.Params["ModuleID"].ToString() == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Content.aspx?ModuleID=1");
    }
}
```

when Module Id is blank then it creates null reference exception.

Comment: You already said where the error is.  When ModuleID is blank (i.e. doesn't exist), Params["ModuleID"] returns null.

Answer (score 8):

Just take out the call to `ToString()`:

```
if (Request.Params["ModuleID"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("Content.aspx?ModuleID=1");
}
```

Currently you're trying to call `ToString` on a null reference.

This won't redirect if the ModuleID is present but empty though. You may want:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["ModuleID"]))
{
    Response.Redirect("Content.aspx?ModuleID=1");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the Request.Params["ModuleID"] on null. An null does not have a .ToString(), that is why you get this exception.
If you use the following code you should not get an NullReferenceException.

```
if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("content.aspx")) 
{ 
    if (Request.Params["ModuleID"] == null) 
    { 
        Response.Redirect("Content.aspx?ModuleID=1"); 
    } 
}
```